# Converting MySQL Queries to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Can anyone please help converting the MySQL query below to SQL Server.

The 'DATE_FORMAT' and the LIMIT:limit are the problem.

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(e.eventTime, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') eventTime,
    e.displayPath, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(source, '/alm:', -1) name,
    e.eventType,
    CASE WHEN e.priority = 0 THEN 'Diagnostic' WHEN e.priority = 1 THEN 'Low' WHEN e.priority = 2 THEN 'Medium' WHEN e.priority = 3 THEN 'High' WHEN e.priority = 4 THEN 'Critical' ELSE '' END priority,
    COALESCE(COALESCE(COALESCE(d.intvalue, d.floatvalue), d.strvalue), '') eventValue,
    COALESCE(ack.strvalue, '') ackUser
FROM 
    alarm_events e 
        LEFT JOIN alarm_event_data d ON d.id = e.id AND d.propname = 'eventValue' 
        LEFT JOIN alarm_event_data ack ON ack.id = e.id AND ack.propname = 'ackUser'
WHERE 
    eventtime BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate AND priority BETWEEN :minPriority AND :maxPriority AND
    ((:active AND e.eventtype = 0) OR (:clear AND e.eventtype = 1) OR (:ack AND e.eventtype = 2))
ORDER BY 
    e.eventTime DESC
LIMIT :limit
```

Comment: Does your current query even _run_ on MySQL?  AFAIK the value following `LIMIT` cannot be a statement parameter.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you done any internet searches or read anything from the manual?  Finding the SQL Server equivalent to `LIMIT` is probably easier to accomplish than writing this question.

Comment: Have you read the SQL Server documentation, [FORMAT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) yet?

Comment: FYI you shouldn't need to nest Coalesce like that.  It takes things in the order of input and takes more than 2 inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in SQL use an @ instead of the : so you would need to adjust for that and populate your variables from the application.

Instead of the LIMIT parameter, you'd begin the query with a [SELECT TOP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) @limit

The SUBSTRING_INDEX function needs to be adjusted to a standard SUBSTRING and PATINDEX function.

You would need to use the [FORMAT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of DATE_FORMAT() function ().

As mentioned in the comments, using additional COALESCE() functions in SQL Server is unnecessary.

So the final query would look something like this (with variables to be set by your calling program):

```
SELECT TOP (@limit)
    FORMAT(e.eventTime, 'M/d/yy hh:mm:ss tt') eventTime,
    e.displayPath, 
    SUBSTRING(source, patindex(source,'/alm:'),len(source)) name,
    e.eventType,
    CASE WHEN e.priority = 0 THEN 'Diagnostic' WHEN e.priority = 1 THEN 'Low' WHEN e.priority = 2 THEN 'Medium' WHEN e.priority = 3 THEN 'High' WHEN e.priority = 4 THEN 'Critical' ELSE '' END priority,
    COALESCE(d.intvalue, d.floatvalue, d.strvalue, '') eventValue,
    COALESCE(ack.strvalue, '') ackUser
FROM 
    alarm_events e 
        LEFT JOIN alarm_event_data d ON d.id = e.id AND d.propname = 'eventValue' 
        LEFT JOIN alarm_event_data ack ON ack.id = e.id AND ack.propname = 'ackUser'
WHERE 
    eventtime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate AND priority BETWEEN @minPriority AND @maxPriority AND
    ((@active AND e.eventtype = 0) OR (@clear AND e.eventtype = 1) OR (@ack AND e.eventtype = 2))
ORDER BY 
    e.eventTime DESC
```